# UIDocumentInteractionController Open Menu Cancelled Callback

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, uidocumentinteraction

I am currently developing an application specifically for iOS7 that utilizes UIDocumentInteractionController open in menu and need a method that notifies me when a user cancels and does not choose an available option.

UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate offers:

```
- (void)documentInteractionControllerDidDismissOptionsMenu:(UIDocumentInteractionController *) controller
```

but this does not specify whether the user tapped one of the available options or cancel.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**NOTE: This will not work for iOS 8 anymore, only iOS7 and earlier**

To determine whether the user has canceled the menu or selected an option, you have to make use of the following delegate methods:

1-

```
- (void)documentInteractionController:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
           didEndSendingToApplication:(NSString *)application
{
    //get called only when the user selected an option and then the delegate method bellow get called
    // Set flag here _isOptionSelected = YES;
    _isOptionSelected = YES;
}
```

2-

```
- (void)documentInteractionControllerDidDismissOpenInMenu:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
{
    //called whether the user has selected option or not
    // check your flag here 
    if(_isOptionSelected == NO) {
        //the user has canceled the menu
     }
    _isOptionSelected = NO;
}
```

**iOS 8**

For iOS 8 and above, use this method instead of the one in step 2:

```
- (void)documentInteractionController:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
           didEndSendingToApplication:(NSString *)application
```

Comment: This won't work, `DidDismissOpenInMenu` is called before `DidEndSendingToApplication`. You need to use `WillBeginSendingToApplication` instead.

Comment: lukech is right.  This answer is on the right track but flawed, despite the multiple up votes and bounty.  I think Basheer_CAD had the answer, but the post had a typo.  You need to check WillBegin... rather than DidEnd... to determine if the user selected an app.

Comment: Thanks @BuvinJ, please edit the answer I will approve your edit, thank you

Comment: I provided an edit.  I tried to not change too much!  It's similar to what I'm using now for iOS 5 through 8.

Comment: I think my edits are being rejected, as they are disappearing.  I don't know how that works. I'm not getting any direct notification of it.

Comment: @BuvinJ, unfortunately your edit was not approved by admins, there was more rejects votes than approves

Comment: Ok... I don't get that, since my edits are definitively accurate.  Thanks for the explanation Basheer!

Comment: @Basheer_CAD, why don't you just edit it instead of waiting that someone else do it and his change get approved? if you edit it it doesn't need approval

Answer (score 0):

## This will work on iOS7 && iOS8

```
BOOL didSelectOptionFromDocumentController = NO;//**set this to "NO" every time you present your documentInteractionController too

-(void)documentInteractionController:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller willBeginSendingToApplication:(NSString *)application {
    didSelectOptionFromDocumentController = YES;
}


-(void)documentInteractionControllerDidDismissOpenInMenu:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller {
    if (didSelectOptionFromDocumentController == NO) {//user cancelled.
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### This works for iOS8 & iOS9 for 3rd party apps AND System Apps!

It's not pretty but it works.

Can anyone tell me if this will pass App Review? Not sure as I'm referring to a class name which is not publicly accessible (_UIDocumentActivityViewController). 
This is Swift 2.2!

NSObject Extension to get a string of the class name:

```
extension NSObject {
    var theClassName: String {
        return NSStringFromClass(self.dynamicType)
    }
}
```

Your Viewcontroller where you're calling the UIDocumentInteractionController from:

```
var appOpened = false
var presentedVCMonitoringTimer: NSTimer!
var docController: UIDocumentInteractionController!

func openDocController() {
    docController = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL: yourURL!)
    docController.UTI = "your.UTI"
    docController.delegate = self
    docController.presentOptionsMenuFromRect(CGRectZero, inView: self.view, animated: true)

    // Check the class of the presentedViewController every 2 seconds
    presentedVCMonitoringTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector: #selector(self.checkPresentedVC), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func checkPresentedVC() {
    if let navVC = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
        print(navVC.presentedViewController?.theClassName)
        if navVC.presentedViewController != nil && (navVC.presentedViewController?.theClassName)! != "_UIDocumentActivityViewController" && (navVC.presentedViewController?.theClassName)! != self.theClassName {
            // A system App was chosen from the 'Open In' dialog
            // The presented ViewController is not the DocumentInteractionController (anymore) and it's not this viewcontroller anymore (could be for example the MFMailComposeViewController if the user chose the mail app)
            appOpened = true
            presentedVCMonitoringTimer?.invalidate()
            presentedVCMonitoringTimer = nil
        }
    }
}

func documentInteractionControllerDidDismissOptionsMenu(controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) {
    print("dismissedOptionsMenu")
    presentedVCMonitoringTimer?.invalidate()
    presentedVCMonitoringTimer = nil
    if appOpened {
        // Do your thing. The cancel button was not pressed
        appOpened = false
    }
    else {
        // Do your thing. The cancel button was pressed
    }
}

func documentInteractionController(controller: UIDocumentInteractionController, willBeginSendingToApplication application: String?) {
    // A third party app was chosen from the 'Open In' menu.
    appOpened = true
    presentedVCMonitoringTimer?.invalidate()
    presentedVCMonitoringTimer = nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 4, use this:

```
 func documentInteractionControllerDidDismissOpenInMenu(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) {

        // this function get called when users finish their work, 
        // either for sharing thing within the same app or exit to other app will do
 }
```

I use it when after users have shared image to Facebook and Instagram.