# Open Instagram only in UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, instagram, social-networking

My application required to post an image to Instagram, I used `UIDocumentInteractionController` to open image file saved in the `Documents directory` with an extension `.igo`. Set  `com.instagram.exclusivegram` as the `UIDocumentInteractionController's` `UTI` property. That all worked fine, my problem is that when I use

```
[dic presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

to open the `UIDocumentInteractionController`, it shows `PDF reader`, `DropBox` etc. I have to hide the other options than `Instagram` or show `Instagram` only. And also how to identify the `Cancel button` press in the presented menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Why is my `UIDocumentInteractionController` showing other options?

   If you're using some code snippet from the Internet, make sure you implemented the delegate method correctly.

   ```
   -(UIDocumentInteractionController *)setupControllerWithURL:(NSURL *)fileURL 
                                                usingDelegate:(id<UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>) interactionDelegate 
   {
       // if you're creating a new instance here,
       // make sure you set the properties correctly
       UIDocumentInteractionController *interactionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:fileURL];
       // remember to set it again here
       interactionController.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
       interactionController.delegate = interactionDelegate;    
       return interactionController;
   }
   ```
2. How can I know if a user cancel the action or proceed to Instagram?

   Please refer to the answer of this thread:  [UIDocumentInteractionController Open Menu Cancelled Callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21640359/uidocumentinteractioncontroller-open-menu-cancelled-callback).

Comment: Thanks @ChengYu Hsu I've solved my first issue, now airDrop shows only Instagram. Trying to solve my second issue.

Comment: What's the equivalent of this in swift?